# eclipse CVS usage: clean timestamps

Tags: eclipse, cvs, timestamp

during synchronisation with the CVS server, eclipse compares the content of the files (of course it uses internally CVS commands). But files without any content change are also shown as different, if they have another timestamp, because they are "touched". You always have to look manually per file comparison dialog if there was really a change in it or not.

Due to auto-generation I have some files that always get new timestamps and therefore I always have to check manually if they really contain any change.

At the [eclipse docu](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-33.htm) I read :

> Update and Commit Operations
>
> There are several flavours of update and commit operations available
>   in the Synchronize view. You can perform the standard update and
>   commit operation on all visible applicable changes or a selected
>   subset. You can also choose to override and update, thus ignoring any
>   local changes, or override and commit, thus making the remote resource
>   match the contents of the local resource. You can also choose to **clean
>   the timestamps for files that have been modified locally** (perhaps by
>   an external build tool) but whose contents match that of the server.

**That's exactly what I want to do**. But I don't know how!? There is no further description/manual ...

Did anybody use this functionality and can help me (maybe even post a screenshot)?

Thanks in advance,

Mayoares

Comment: Not strictly related to your question, but maybe you can consider not storing auto-generated artifacts in CVS.

Comment: Eli, you are right, auto-generated files need not be stored in CVS. To ask the question as short as possible I was not exact enough. My problematic files are not auto-generated,but - let's say - auto-adapted. They are in XML structure and they are adapted via XSLT. So it might happen, that they have other changes (manual ones) than the auto-adaption changes.

Comment: This is also (still) an issue if working with a FAT volume locally, and twice per year the daylight saving is applied to the clock... Synchronization then takes very long, because Eclipse checks mostly all files.

Answer (score 0):

When you perform a CVS Update on a project (using context menu `Team->Update`), Eclipse implicitly updates the timestamp of local files whose contents match that of the server.

Comment: Doing the update won't change the timestamps in my case. It just says "no changes in CVS" and the "changed file" marker remains.

Comment: The only feature that will change the timestamp in eclipse, as far as I have found out so far, is `Team` -> `Revert to base`.